# "cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I am writing down a simple code to loop through all the links in a range, gather info from those spreadsheets (links) and paste in the current row of the loop.

```html
function UpdateProjects()
{

//----------EDIT THIS FOR A DIFFERENT CLIENT-------------
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects");
  var etilastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var urlRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, etilastrow);
  var urlsvalues = urlRange.getValues();
  var urls = urlRange.getFormulas();
  Logger.log(urls)

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < etilastrow; ++i) {
   currentRow = 2 + i;
  var dirturl = urls[i];
  var remove_before = dirturl[i].indexOf('",');
    var url = dirturl[i].substring(12, remove_before);

Logger.log(currentRow);
    Logger.log(url);

//-----------------Loop code below until last project-------
  var projectPCBdesignsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Main");
    var lstrow = projectPCBdesignsheet.getLastRow(); 

  const vA=projectPCBdesignsheet.getRange(7,2,lstrow).getValues();//get data from project's PCB Design sheet
   
//add last edit values  
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 4).setValue(vA[10]);
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 5).setValue(vA[11]);    

//additional data from PCB design sheet
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 6).setValue(vA[0]);
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 7).setValue(vA[1]);
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 8).setValue(vA[2]);
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 9).setValue(vA[3]);  
  sheet.getRange(currentRow, 11).setValue(vA[5]); 
}
}
```

Script works if I hard code an url into the variable. Right now, from the log, I can see the row number and the clean url.

Problem is that the script stops with this error :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
ETIUpdateProjects
@ UpdateProjects.gs:18"

I don't understand how it can find an error at row 18 if it shows me the log of currentRow and url, that come after the "indexOf" row.

Comment: `etilastrow` should be not used that way because you start getting rows from 2nd, not 1st, can you substract from it and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

**Issue 1:**

Starting from the second row, you get one empty cell extra in the data:

```
var urlRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, etilastrow);
```

this will give you something like: `[[=link],['']]`

this can be fixed by changing `etilastrow` to `etilastrow-1`.

and also the same in the `for` loop.

**Issue 2:**

Even if you fix issue 1, the main issue in the current code which also produces the error you are getting is in these lines:

```
var dirturl = urls[i];
var remove_before = dirturl[i].indexOf('",');
```

Remember, `urls` is an array of `etilastrow` rows but only **one** column. If you paraphrase your code, what you call is essentially `urls[i][i]`. This will return `undefined` after the second iteration, when `i` becomes `1`, because there is only one column in the data.

The reason your code works, is because you are testing it with one cell filled in and therefore `urls[0][0]` works properly, but if you add more URLs the second index will increase to more than `0` and this for example `urls[0][1]` will drop and error because `urls` has only one column.

To solve this issue you could change:

```
var dirturl = urls[i];
var remove_before = dirturl[i].indexOf('",');
var url = dirturl[i].substring(12, remove_before);
```

to:

```
var dirturl = urls[i];
var remove_before = dirturl[0].indexOf('",');
var url = dirturl[0].substring(12, remove_before);
```

### Improvements:

**Improvement 1:**

I would advice you to get read of the `for` loops because they can be confusing when dealing with indexes and arrays and you need to be comfortable enough to handle them. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to work with each url directly:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects");
  var etilastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var urlRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, etilastrow-1);
  var urlsvalues = urlRange.getValues();
  var urls = urlRange.getFormulas();


  urls.flat().forEach((r,i)=>{
    let currentRow = i + 2;
    let remove_before = r.indexOf('",');
    let url = r.substring(12, remove_before);
    console.log(url)
    console.log(currentRow)
    // put here the rest of your code
  })
```

**Improvement 2:**

From Google Apps Script point of view calling `setValue` many times but also within a `for` loop can cost a lot of performance. According to [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) the proper way to do that, is to store the values in an array and then use `setValues` instead outside of the for loop. In this way, you use only `setValues` once.

I could try to optimize that part of your code but the answer is not going to be helpful enough because there are already many posts regarding this optimization but also your code should work with the corrections I indicated.

Comment: Marios, thanks a lot for your help and for reserving some time for this.
I made some modifications as per you advice and I also updated the setValue with a single setValues.
Script works fast and well. There's a minor issue tho: the forEach loop won't terminate until it finds an empty cell, with no url. This through an "invalid argument : url". I noticed that it is not possible to return, break or continue this type of loop so I imagine it is not possible to solve this with an if (url == "").
Thanks again for your support. Really, really appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I also tried to have this script running when the user select that specific sheet (info will on be updated when it's necessary). 
My basic skills on GAS lead to a script like this that unfortunately doesn't work.

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // Run update script when sheet is selected
  var sheet = e.sheet;
  var ssname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if(ssname === "Projects")
  {
    UpdateProjects();
  }
}

Comment: @Andre8426 glad your issue was resolved. `forEach` will terminate at the end of the array. If you won't to terminate before that I am afraid you need to use a `for` loop. Performance wise you don't lose anything with a for loop, so if you want to `break` or `continue` my advice would be to continue using the for loop.

Comment: @Andre8426 I would advice you to post a new question regarding the modification. Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Sorry for the inconvenience.